# Inserting multiple values in a table, in C#

Tags: c#

I have 98 columns in a table named 'molasses_analysis' and I need to insert records using my c# desktop application.
**Sample** of my code is as below.

```
    string insert_sql = @"insert into molasses_analysis(mo_entry_date, mo_entry_time, mo_code, mo_brix, mo_pol, mo_purity, mo_crtd_by) " +
    " values(@entry_date, @entry_time, @mol_code, @brix, @pol, @purity, @crtd_by)";
    try
        {
         List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>();
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@entry_date", entry_date));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@entry_time", entry_time));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@mol_code", mol_code));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@brix", brix));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@pol", pol));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@purity", purity));
         param.Add(new SqlParameter("@crtd_by", crtd_by));
        int inserted_rows = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(dbConn.sqlConn(),CommandType.Text, insert_sql, param.ToArray());
        }
catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Data not saved!\nError message - "+ex.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
```

Here I just used seven fields/columns only but it will be quite hectic and painful to write such code for 98 columns and assign **Sql Parameter** for each column.
My question is, is there any cleaner and good code to insert multiple columns using c# code?

Comment: Not really, no. You can make the whole thing dynamic, by having a list of columns and their values, but you're still going to have to execute what ends up as something similar.

Comment: No there isn't AFAIK. You should look into EntityFramework, or a similar library. Saves you a lot of time by managing all this stuff for you.

Comment: The "best" you can do is to build up your SQL statement dynamically, by having a dictionary or list of the columns you need to add values into, and a similar list (or the same dictionary/list) with the values you need to place into those columns, then you combine all of this using loops to concatenate the right SQL and add all the parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no; Not with the way you're using local variables to populate each `SqlParameter`.

One solution would be if each of those local variables was instead stored in a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) (key/value pairs) you could use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) and iterate your dictionary keys to build the SQL query string. During that same loop you could add each `SqlParameter`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic; // for dictionary
using System.Text; // for stringbuilder

// ...

// create a dictionary then use a literal to make it easier to populate
Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "entry_date", "SOMEVALUE1" }, 
    { "entry_time", "SOMEVALUE2" }
    // add more params and values here...
};

// start our query and params list
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("YOUR QUERY STARTS HERE");
List<SqlParameter> params = new List<SqlParameter>();

// iterate over each key/value pair, appending to the query and params list
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in data) {
    query.Append("@" + pair.Key);
    params.Add(new SqlParameter(pair.Key, pair.Value));
}
```

**NOTE**: The above code is an *EXAMPLE* to demonstrate using dictionaries and stringbuilders; It should be studied, not be copy-pasted.

Answer (score 1):

If your property names and columns names are same this answer will help you.
First, get your column names with SQL code which is given below

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'molasses_analysis';
//this returns column names and column types
```

Then assign table to list which contains column names

```
List<string> listColNames = new List<string>();
```

Then create your sqlInsert string with loop

```
foreach (string item in listColNames) {
    params.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + item, item));
}
```